# Why I can't change the height of the dropdown ui element?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Dropdown]

The height is grayed out disabled.

I can enabled it and then change the width and height if I disable the Vertical Layout Group (Script) on the MainMenuPanel but then when disable it and change the height and then when enable back the Vertical Layout Group (Script) on the MainMenuPanel it's changing back again the ResolutionDropdown height value to it's old original value and never keep the new value I changed it to :

[image: Main Menu Panel]

Comment: The purpose of the VerticalLayoutGroup is the take control of the list for layout and element size.  That is why they are locked when the VerticalLayoutGroup is active.  There are toggles in the VerticalLayoutGroup where you can choose to have the child control its own width and/or height.

Comment: [I wonder what this does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP83i.png).

Comment: @Draco18s that's probably the quickest fix to get the vertical layout group working. However, I believe a vertical layout group is not valuable here, since it appears the elements are static. Utilizing a canvas scalar is probably the best option in this use case.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Possibly, though if you think that that is the case, your posted answer doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Draco18s You are correct. I should add that as a disclaimer. I figure it's better for Daniel to come to that conclusion for his own use case. A Vertical Layout Group is technically more dynamic and may be useful if he has more changes planned for his menu. Do you mind if I add your snippet highlighting the control child size as well?

Comment: Another thing to note @Draco18s, is that unchecking the control child size values would result in Daniel having to manually control each of the layout elements manually. It depends on his use case.

Comment: @ErikOverflow Sure, go ahead. Its just a snip of the asker's own image, I didn't do anything that I feel I have/want rights to. And sure, unchecking it might cause other problems, it was just odd that the choice for the layout group to control child size was made (all those checkboxes are off by default), only to result in asking why manual control was no longer possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your UI Elements are not meant to be dynamic, you probably don't have an explicit need for a layout group. Vertical Layout groups are most useful when the UI elements can change during runtime. Grid Layout groups can be used to create a responsive UI, but that doesn't seem to be your problem here.

That being said, the fastest solution can probably be achieved per @Draco18s's comment above by unticking the "Control Child Size" values for your layout group. As a result, your UI elements will only have their positions controlled and not their size. Be wary that you will need to manually set the height of each of your UI elements rather than rely on the Layout Group.

If you **do** want to have the layout group control most of your element's heights and have the dropdown be an exception, you can add a [LayoutElement](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-LayoutElement.html) component to your dropdown GameObject and modify the minimum and preferred values (the height values in this use case).

From Unity's documentation on [Vertical Layout Groups](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html):

> The Vertical Layout Group component places its child layout elements on top of each other. Their heights are determined by their respective minimum, preferred, and flexible heights according to the following model:
>
> - The minimum heights of all the child layout elements are added together and the spacing between them is added as well. The result is the mimimum height of the Vertical Layout Group.
> - The preferred heights of all the child layout elements are added together and the spacing between them is added as well. The result is the preferred height of the Vertical Layout Group.
> - If the Vertical Layout Group is at its minimum height or smaller, all the child layout elements will also have their minimum height.
> - The closer the Vertical Layout group is to its preferred height, the closer each child layout element will also get to their preferred height.
> - If the Vertical Layout Group is taller than its preferred height, it will distribute the extra available space proportionally to the child layout elements according to their respective flexible heights.

I recommend reading Unity's documentation on [Unity's UI Auto Layout system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIAutoLayout.html)